# Using if/else in insert and update statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a staging table (in SQL SERVER 2008) with nullable fields.
I want to Insert or Update the records from the staging table to main table.
During this I want a comparison to be done

```
Update main
set main.field1 = (
if(staging.field1 isnull)
    then ---- 
else if(staging.field2 isnull)
    then ---- 
else
    then
)
```

How can I embed the above condition in my insert and update statements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The (sort of) equivalent is to use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expressions:

```
UPDATE main
SET main.field1 =
  CASE
    WHEN staging.field1 IS NULL
      THEN --
    WHEN staging.field2 IS NULL
      THEN --
    ELSE --
  END;
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention.. the condition must be on priority basis.

Comment: The *priority* is in the order you list them. So in this example priority would be given to the `field1` expression followed by `field2`. The first qualifying expression is the one whose value is assigned to `main.field1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO main
   USING staging
      ON main.id = staging.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET field1 = COALESCE( staging.field1 , main.field1 ), 
      SET field2 = COALESCE( staging.field2 , main.field2 ), 
      ... ;
```